# How to do database migration from source code with Beego framework?

Tags: database, go, database-migration, beego

I am using Beego framework in Golang. Whenever I add new table or column to the database, I want the code to do the migration. Is there any flag I can specify in code to migrate the database automatically in new release?

I don't want to run this `bee migrate -conn="username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb"` whenever I make db changes.

Comment: You can create a post build stage in your deployment process that runs these tasks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`orm.RunSyncdb`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/beego/beego/v2@v2.0.1/client/orm#RunSyncdb):

```
err := orm.RunSyncdb("default", false, true)
```

See Documentation: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md#generate-tables